# Create bootstrap alert in push notification page using nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page display information from MySQL automatically using NodeJS. How do I make the text username or description appear as a bootstrap alert such as "alert alert-info"?

```js
<time></time>
<div id="container">Loading ...</div>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
// create a new websocket
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
// on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
var usersList = "<dl>";
$.each(data.users,function(index,user){
  usersList += "<dt>" + user.user_name + "</dt>\n" +
         "<dd>" + user.user_description + "\n" + "</dd>";
});
usersList += "</dl>";
$('#container').html(usersList);

$('time').html('Last Update:' + data.time);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with predefined (hidden) modal with placeholders to be replaced with dynamic data, and trigger show on notification

something like (pseudocode in notification function body)

```
 $("#myModal .modal-body").html('my content');
 $("#myModal").modal();
```

(sample of bootstrap modal triggered programatically )

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_js&stacked=h